# Upload files in nodejs to another service

Tags: node.js, api

how do i send a local photo file to a rest api?
I have a service entirely in nodeJS that receives messages and sends, however, I would like to be able to do the same for other files. I can download the files and store them in an image folder, but I don't know how to get that same image and send it to another server

The download function takes a download url (https:example.com/id=123/file.jpg/123321) and file name (file.jpg) and downloads the file to the requested folder.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");

//download function
let download = async (url, fileName) => {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(`./src/temp/${fileName}`);
  const request = https.get(url, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);

    file.on("finish", () => {
      file.close();
      console.log("Download Completed");
    });
  });
};

//POST function
let controllerMessage = async (received_message, user, type, res) => {
  var body = {
    body: received_message,
    user: user,
    type: type,
  };
  try {
    await axios.post(URL_SERVER, body).then(async (response) => {
      sendMessage(response.data);
    });
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

I need to get this file and send it to another server

Comment: Share some code. Do you know about the `fs` functions that can open a stream to a local file? Ultimately you want to open a stream and then pass that stream to a HTTP client. How that works depends on your http client.

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Comment: I had done something similar in another code

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('chat_id', chatId);
        formData.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(`url\\${photo}`));
        formData.append('caption', caption);

        const response = await axios.post(`${TELEGRAM_API}/sendPhoto`, formData, {
            headers: formData.getHeaders(),
        });

but I didn't find any way to concatenate with JSON. in this version, I just need the json body to receive formData.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(...)